# Is there a stated range for Elemental Attunement?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk

Reading through the text for the Elemental Attunement class feature, from the Monk class, it seems as though there's not a hard range given. To quote the effect:

> Elemental Attunement. You can use your action to briefly control elemental forces **nearby**, causing one of the following effects of your choice:
>
> - Create a harmless, instantaneous sensory effect...
> - [and so forth] (PHB p.81)

The only official range I've been able to find stated is nearby, which is unusually squirrely for rules.

Is there an official statement on the range of this feature?

Comment: Elemental Attunement isn't a cantrip, it is a class feature.

Comment: Whooooop time to fix that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing written on Element Attunement is what is on PHB p.81.  The term "nearby" has no official game definition, so regualar usage rules apply, and the DM makes a call if something is too far away to be nearby.

Senisible limits *might* be set at any of the following, with reasons a a DM might choose them:

- 5 feet, as it is adjacent to you on a grid system.
- 10 feet, as that is a reasonable distance to be to a candle or torch you might need to light, or food you want to cook/cool.
- Line of sight, you can't know it is nearby or aim it, if you can't see it.

This class feature is similar to the cantrips *druid craft*, *thaumaturgy*, and *prestidigitation*, in that that it isn't a combat feature but a utility/role play feature.  I would assume the vague range is a product of either: it being a utility or RP effect where moving to use it doesn't typically affect action economies, the clever usages already require the DM to make a call on weather the use is legit, or they just got lazy on this one :) . Regardless of why, no there is nothing more specific.